# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `myroutes` where `id` = 14 limit 1)

Tags: database, laravel, routes

Using Laravel I was able to post data from the database, buy getting it all. But I need it to get only the data that has the same user_id as the user logged in.

When I try to select one of the output data or try the link to it, I receive the following error *"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `myroutes` where `id` = 14 limit 1)"* yet everywhere I have "myroute_id" which is the correct column in the database.

web.php

```
Route::get('/my-saved-routes', function () {

$myroutes = DB::table('myroutes')->latest()->get();

return view('myroutes.index', compact('myroutes'));
});

Route::get('/my-saved-routes/{myroute_id}', function ($myroute_id) {    

$myroute = DB::table('myroutes')->find($myroute_id);

return view('myroutes.show', compact('myroute'));
});
```

myroutes.index

```
    @foreach ($myroutes as $myroute)
    <ul>

        <a href="/my-saved-routes/{{ $myroute->myroute_id }}">
            <li>{{ $myroute->start }} - {{ $myroute->end }}</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

myroutes.show

```
<ul>
    <li>{{ $myroute->myroute_id }}</li> 
    <li>{{ $myroute->start }}</li>
    <li>{{ $myroute->end }}</li>
    <li>{{ $myroute->waypoints }}</li>
</ul>
```

Database

Database-img
[image]

Comment: the error is pretty self-explanatory; there is no `id` in `myroutes`

Comment: Yes and I have referenced all as myroute_id so where is it getting id from? @Napoli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find()` always uses the `id` column. You have to use this:

```
$myroute = DB::table('myroutes')->where('myroute_id', $myroute_id)->first();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

your query will be like this way

```
$data = DB::table('myroutes')->where('user_id',$yourId)->get();
dd($data);
```